# Vertical alignment of lists with different content in bash

Tags: string, bash, command-line, text-alignment

Assume two lists with different content. For simplicity, let us assume that these lists contain only alphanumeric strings. I would like to combine and vertically align the two lists in `bash`.

```
user$ cat file1
foo
foo
bar
qux

user$ cat file2
foo
bar
bar
baz
qux

user$ sought_command file1 file2
foo foo
foo -
bar bar
- bar
- baz
qux qux
```

The delimiter between the values per line (here a single whitespace) does not need to be selected by the user, but can be hard-coded. So can the placeholder for a gap (here a dash).

**EDIT:**

Ideally, this command is not restricted to two input lists, but can take any number of input files, each comparing to the first one specified.

```
user$ sought_command file1 file2 file2
foo foo foo
foo - -
bar bar bar
- bar bar
- baz baz
qux qux qux
```

Comment: At first glance, it looks like `comm` could be the tool you need.  You'd need to post-process the output to translate the missing fields properly.  However, it requires sorted inputs, so it probably isn't the right tool for the job after all unless the order of the output doesn't matter.  Almost certainly, `awk` (or Perl or Python, or …) would be needed.  You can't use `paste` because of your content-matching requirements.  Doing it with more than 2 files makes Perl or Python more likely to be appropriate than `awk`, though you probably could do it in `awk` if you really worked hard.

Comment: Which version of bash?

Comment: @cdarke Ideally, the code would work for GNU bash 4.3.46

Comment: The output from `diff -u` could also be useful as a starting point, though you'll need to post-process it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `diff` with `-y` flag to get:

```
$ diff -y file1 file2
foo                             foo
foo                               <
bar                             bar
                                  > bar
                                  > baz
qux                             qux
```

and together with `tr` and `sed`:

```
$ diff -t -y file1 file2 | tr -s ' ' | sed 's/[<>]/-/' 
foo foo
foo -
bar bar
 - bar
 - baz
qux qux
```

Comment: @OhadEytan Excellent answer! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very likely faster version of Ohad Eytan's answer, only relevant for extremely large or many files:

```
diff -t -y file1 file2 | tr -s ' ' | tr '[<>]' '-' | grep -o '\S\+ \S\+'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `diff` and `sed` will work when comparing just 2 files

```
diff -y file1 file2 | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/ /g' | sed 's/[<,>]/- /g'
```

Results (line up nicely):

```
foo foo
foo -
bar bar
 -  bar
 -  baz
qux qux
```

Will need more work in order to handle input files greater than 2.

Comment: We don't even get an upvote for an alternative solution?  ;-(